# php executing python works locally but not when curl loaded

Tags: php, python, curl

I have a a php web page where I can go to to click 2 buttons, on and off. They are connected to a relay that is operated via python.

```html
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['on']))
    {
         exec('sudo python on.py');
    }
?>
    <form method="post">
    <p>
        <button name="on">On</button>
    </p>
    </form>
 
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['off']))
    {
         exec('sudo python off.py');
    }
?>
    <form method="post">
    <p>
        <button name="off">Off</button>
    </p>
    </form>
```

This all works fine when you access the page directly. I have a separate web page on a separate device that I want to be able to load all these other pages.

```html
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.1.100/index.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

This seems to render the remote page, buttons and all, but when clicked, the python script does not run. I'm sure I am missing some crucial piece here, I'm not an expert programmer and trying to use 3 new languages here so I could use some help.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have 2 servers, *server A* is the one with the *second* snippet, while *server B* is the one with the *first* snippet *and* the *python program*. The *browser* connects to *server A*; *server A* request to *server B* to get the page content and finally renders back the content to *server B*. When *server A* requests to *server B* the *off* form field is not set, so the code is not executed:

```
browser -> server A -> server B
```

Then, you click on the button, so the *browser* does another request to *server A*, this time the *browser* sends a value for the *off* form field; again the *server A* makes the same request to *server B* (without the *off* form field) and code is not executed.

Your problem is *server A* is not sending the *off* form field.

I recomend you add 2 PHP programs in *server B*:

*on.php*

```
<?php
exec('sudo python on.py');
?>
```

*off.php*

```
<?php
exec('sudo python off.py');
?>
```

So you have 2 different pages for *on* and *off*. Then on *server A* you call one of these depending on the *off* parameter from the *server A*:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['on']))
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.1.100/on.php");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_exec($ch);
    }
?>
    <form method="post">
    <p>
        <button name="on">On</button>
    </p>
    </form>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['off']))
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.1.100/off.php");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_exec($ch);
    }
?>
    <form method="post">
    <p>
        <button name="off">Off</button>
    </p>
    </form>
```

Your setup is insecure, because anyone can call the script from *server B*, but that is OK if it is a personal project.

Comment: This is what im getting on the remote server

[Fri Aug 07 19:35:04 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.229] File does not exist: /var/www/test1, referer: http://127.0.0.1/test/

I am accessing the page locally on another machine, so the request is different, that path doesn't exist on the remote machine.

Comment: When i browse to the original remote file, everything is fine. The second snippet is located on another server, it pulls the page content but does not execute the python. I feel like Im on the wrong path, what I want is more or less an iframe of each node i add, was hoping to not use iframe, but what I am doing is not working.

Comment: @JoshStevens, I have suggested a different solution for your problem.